# How to include headers in oraclize GET request

Tags: solidity, truffle, oracles

I need to be able to include an API key as a header within my GET request to an api using oraclize in solidity.

The oraclize documentation states that you can define arguments to send however, you must add them to a second bracket and by doing so, this makes the request a POST request.

When I try to do this, the API responds saying I have not included my key as a header.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the computation query. They wrote a library for people to use. https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/computation-datasource/url-requests/urlRequests.sol

Answer (score 0):

Reply to @jazzhole answer.
the repo got updated , here is the [updated link](https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-examples/blob/master/solidity/computation-datasource/url-requests/UrlRequests.sol)